How to generate field values on save
I would like to set the value of the case subject field automatically on saving. The value is made up of the values of the client name and a custom field. Is the postProcess or the post hook the better choice for this? I have tried to do it in postProcess but didn't find the right method to set the field value.

Note that case subject is a required field so you need to either set a default value on form load, or remove the required attribute before saving the form. See https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/

Good point. I used setElementError(NULL) in validateForm and hide the field via CSS in the UI. Otherwise the JavaScript validation will be active.

You can either do it pre() or PostProcess() hook
In postProcess hook you can call below API to update case id 34
\Civi\Api4\CiviCase::update(TRUE)
  ->addValue('subject', 'Your custom value')
  ->addWhere('id', '=', 34)
  ->execute();


Why do I need to explicitly save the entity? Using a hook I would expect to intercept at some point in the call flow, change some values and let the regular process continue. Why can't I just change the submitted form values?

The postprocess hook is called after the entity is saved. So either you need to use buildForm hook to set to default or via JS on form load to save it automatically. The user will be allowed to change the subject field from the form via inspect element or on the form. So it may not end up with the same subject you want to be

I see. The subject field's value depends on values the user enters in other fields. So concatenating these values and setting the subject after submit and before saving the entity appears the best approach to me. What about the pre hook?

pre hook is a better option if the values you will be retrieving is not part of the case

I have solved it by updating submittedValues in buildForm now. I didn't know this hook is called on POST as well. Only downside is that I have to reload contact data and reformat date fields. And buildForm ist not used on API calls.
